# Comparing nested object arrays and returning values that exist JavaScript, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, charts, heatmap

Hi I'm trying to get my numbers fetched from the backend server to a chart library but it seems almost impossible. Below are my codes please help me out.

```
const data = [
    { id: "americano",
       data: [{x: "10",y: 10,}, {x: "11",y: 20,}, {x: "12",y: 40,}, {x: "13",y: 50,}, {x: 14,y:60,}],},
    { id: "latte",
       data: [{x: "10",y: 10,}, {x: "11",y: 20,}, {x: "12",y: 40,}, {x: "13",y: 50,}, {x: 14,y:60,}],},
    { id: "espresso",
       data: [{x: "10",y: 10,}, {x: "11",y: 20,}, {x: "12",y: 40,}, {x: "13",y: 50,}, {x: 14,y:60,}],},
]
```

the data I need for library chart for any x value missing, the chart collapses so I need all values however the problem is the data from our backend server, there aren't all data needed.

```
const serverdata = [
    { "id": "latte",
        "data": [{"x": "12", "y": 30}]},
    {"id": "americano",
        "data": [{"x": "10","y": 20},{ "x": "13","y": 10}]},
    {"id": "espresso",
        "data": [{"x": "10","y": 30},{ "x": "11","y": 10},{ "x": "12","y": 20}]},
  ]
```

data i get from the backend server

here's what i tried

i tried putting the following value instead of the y value in the data

```
const returnExistingValues = (a) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
           for (let k = 0; k < data[i].data.length; k++) {
              for (let l = 0; l < a[j].data.length; l++) {
            if (
              ((data[i].menuName === a[j].menuName)) &&
              ((data[i].data[k].x === a[j].data[l].x))
            ) {
                return a[j].data[l].y;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

for example

```
const data = [
    { id: "americano",
       data: [{x: "10",y: returnExistingValues(serverdata),}
    ]
  }
]
```

all the returnExistingValues function is doing is returning 0 for the values :(
anyone please help me out?

below is the expected result

```
const newData = [
    { id: "americano",
      data: [{x: "10",y: 20,}, {x: "11",y: 0,}, {x: "12",y: 0,}, {x: "13",y: 10,}, {x: 14,y:0,}],},
    { id: "latte",
       data: [{x: "10",y: 0,}, {x: "11",y: 0,}, {x: "12",y: 30,}, {x: "13",y: 0,}, {x: 14,y:0,}],},
    { id: "espresso",
       data: [{x: "10",y: 0,}, {x: "11",y: 30,}, {x: "12",y: 10,}, {x: "13",y: 20,}, {x: 14,y:0,}],},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is impossible!
Here is my solution:

```
const serverdata = [
    { "id": "latte",
        "data": [{"x": "12", "y": 30}]},
    {"id": "americano",
        "data": [{"x": "10","y": 20},{ "x": "13","y": 10}]},
    {"id": "espresso",
        "data": [{"x": "10","y": 30},{ "x": "11","y": 10},{ "x": "12","y": 20}]},
  ]


function fillEmptyData(serverdata){

  //Calculate min and max x value from all values
  let max = 0;
  let min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  Object.entries(serverdata).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      for (const item of value.data) { 
        max = item.x > max ? item.x : max;
        min = item.x < min ? item.x : min;
      }
  });

  //Now insert all the values in the new array
  let newarr = serverdata;
  Object.entries(serverdata).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    for(let i = min; i < max; i++){
      //Insert missing values
      newarr[key].data[i-min] = newarr[key].data[i] ?? {x:i, y:0};
    }
  });

  return newarr;
}

console.log(fillEmptyData(serverdata))
```

Comment: Thanks helped a ton! I seem to have gotten closer to my goal but but not quite :(
would there be a way to replace the data with server data for the key and values that only exists? with the data not being changed for key values that don't exist in the server data?

Comment: @errorfulldev Maybe replace {x:i, y:0} with data[key].data[i-min] ?